# php loading csv file to an array with keys

Tags: php, laravel, csv, tinker

I've found some strange thing converting csv file to an array and i can't figure it out why the $data_arr[0]["Name"] is undefined.

The $test_arr is created for comparison only, the expected result is printing $data_arr[0]["Name"] => Jeff

The code is:

```
// load the csv file & convert to an array
$csv_arr = array_map('str_getcsv', file('test.csv'));

// get the first index for the header
$header_arr = $csv_arr[0];

// new array for the data
$data_arr = [];

// skip the first line (header)
for ($i = 1; $i < count($csv_arr); $i++) {

    for ($h = 0; $h < count($header_arr); $h++) {

        // data_arr[0][key] = value ...
        $data_arr[$i - 1][$header_arr[$h]] = trim($csv_arr[$i][$h]);
    }
}

// create a test array
$test_arr = [];

// add the same data to the array as the original
$test_arr[0] = [
    "Name" => "Jeff",
    "Business" => "Google"
];

$test_arr[1] = [
    "Name" => "Bill",
    "Business" => "Microsoft"
];

// test arr print
print_r($test_arr);
print_r($test_arr[0]["Name"]);

// output: Jeff

// original array print
print_r($data_arr);
print_r($data_arr[0]["Name"]);

// output: null - Undefined index: Name
```

$test_arr printed:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Jeff
            [Business] => Google
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Bill
            [Business] => Microsoft
        )

)
```

$data_arr printed:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Jeff
            [Business] => Google
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Bill
            [Business] => Microsoft
        )

)
```

The test.csv file content:

```
Name,Business
Jeff,Google
Bill,Microsoft
```

I've tested the code under laravel tinker

- Laravel version: 8.75
- PHP version: 7.4.3

Comment: _"why the $data_arr "Name" index is always undefined"_ - what are you talking about? In what you have shown as the debug output of $data_arr, there clearly _are_ values ...?

Comment: @CBroe print_r($data_arr[0]["Name"]); - Undefined index: Name, there is value as you can see under $data_arr printed:

Comment: What does `var_dump(array_keys($data_arr[0]));` result in?

Comment: @CBroe array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Name"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "Business"
}

Comment: @CBroe it looks like the name is 7 chars instead of 4

Comment: Probably some sort of "invisible" characters after that column value then. Re-type that part of the CSV manually, or go check what is actually contained there in the first place using a hex editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the .csv file was saved with UTF-8 BOM encoding, with UTF8 encoding (without BOM) it works as expected.

There is my solution to remove the BOM in my code:

```
// load the csv file & convert to an array
$csv_arr = array_map('str_getcsv', file('test.csv'));

// remove BOM
$csv_json = json_encode($csv_arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$csv_json = str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF",'',$csv_json); 
$csv_arr = json_decode($csv_json, true);
```